# laravel multi authentication .These credentials do not match our records

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8. Earlier that code works. But now it's not multi authenticating. I created admincontroller and used the `AuthenticSessionController` function. For the `AttemptToAuthenticate.php`, `LoginResponse.php` and `RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable.php` I used them in the `app\actions\fortify` and `app\response\LoginResponse.php`. Passed the guard to the middleware. The way it worked earlier, I used the same way so it can redirects to the different view page for user and admin.

AdminController:

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline;
    use App\Actions\Fortify\AttemptToAuthenticate;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\PrepareAuthenticatedSession;
    use App\Actions\Fortify\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;
    use App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
    
    class AdminController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * The guard implementation.
         *
         * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
         */
        protected $guard;
    
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard  $guard
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct(StatefulGuard $guard)
        {
            $this->guard = $guard;
        }
    
        public function loginform(){
            return view('auth.login',['guard'=>'admin']);
        }
    
        /**
         * Show the login view.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse
         */
        public function create(Request $request): LoginViewResponse
        {
            return app(LoginViewResponse::class);
        }
    
        /**
         * Attempt to authenticate a new session.
         *
         * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest  $request
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function store(LoginRequest $request)
        {
            return $this->loginPipeline($request)->then(function ($request) {
                return app(LoginResponse::class);
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the authentication pipeline instance.
         *
         * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
         */
        protected function loginPipeline(LoginRequest $request)
        {
            if (Fortify::$authenticateThroughCallback) {
                return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter(
                    call_user_func(Fortify::$authenticateThroughCallback, $request)
                ));
            }
    
            if (is_array(config('fortify.pipelines.login'))) {
                return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter(
                    config('fortify.pipelines.login')
                ));
            }
    
            return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter([
                config('fortify.limiters.login') ? null : EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled::class,
                Features::enabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication()) ? RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class : null,
                AttemptToAuthenticate::class,
                PrepareAuthenticatedSession::class,
            ]));
        }
    
        /**
         * Destroy an authenticated session.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse
         */
        public function destroy(Request $request): LogoutResponse
        {
            $this->guard->logout();
    
            $request->session()->invalidate();
    
            $request->session()->regenerateToken();
    
            return app(LogoutResponse::class);
        }
    }



**AdminStatefulGuard**

    <?php
    
    namespace App\Guards;
    
    interface AdminStatefulGuard extends Guard
    {
        /**
         * Attempt to authenticate a user using the given credentials.
         *
         * @param  array  $credentials
         * @param  bool  $remember
         * @return bool
         */
        public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false);
    
        /**
         * Log a user into the application without sessions or cookies.
         *
         * @param  array  $credentials
         * @return bool
         */
        public function once(array $credentials = []);
    
        /**
         * Log a user into the application.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
         * @param  bool  $remember
         * @return void
         */
        public function login(Authenticatable $user, $remember = false);
    
        /**
         * Log the given user ID into the application.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $id
         * @param  bool  $remember
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|bool
         */
        public function loginUsingId($id, $remember = false);
    
        /**
         * Log the given user ID into the application without sessions or cookies.
         *
         * @param  mixed  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|bool
         */
        public function onceUsingId($id);
    
        /**
         * Determine if the user was authenticated via "remember me" cookie.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function viaRemember();
    
        /**
         * Log the user out of the application.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function logout();
    }



**Admin middleware**
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;
    
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
    class AdminRedirectIfAuthenticated
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @param  string|null  ...$guards
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
        {
            $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;
    
            foreach ($guards as $guard) {
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect($guard."/dashboard");
                }
            }
    
            return $next($request);
        }
    }




 **Kernel.php**
        protected $routeMiddleware = [
            'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
            'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminRedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    
            'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
            'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
            'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
            'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
            'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
            'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
            'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        ];




    **LoginResponse.php**
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Responses;;
    
    use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
    
    class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
    {
        /**
         * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
         */
        public function toResponse($request)
        {
            return $request->wantsJson()
                        ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
                        : redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }

}

**web.php**

    Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>['admin:admin']],function(){
        Route::get('/login',[AdminController::class,'loginform']);
        Route::post('/login',[AdminController::class,'store']);
    
    });
    
    
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum,web', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
    
    
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum,admin', 'verified'])->get('/admin/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');




**ForifyServiceProvider.php**
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Providers;
    
    use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
    use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
    use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
    use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
    use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
    
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
    
    use App\Actions\Fortify\AttemptToAuthenticate;
    
    use App\Actions\Fortify\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;
    use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    
    class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            //
            $this->app->when([
                AdminController::class,
                RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class,
                AttemptToAuthenticate::class
            ])->needs(StatefulGuard::class)->give(function(){
                return Auth::guard('admin');
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Bootstrap any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
            Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
            Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
            Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);
    
            RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
                return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->email.$request->ip());
            });
    
            RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
                return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
            });
        }
    }


**RouteServiceProvider.php**
 public const HOME = '/dashboard';
    public static function redirectTo($guard){
        return $guard."/dashboard";
    }



**Login.blade.php**

    <form method="POST" action="{{ isset($guard)? url($guard.'/login') : route('login') }}">



**AdminSeeder.php**

    <?php
    
    namespace Database\Seeders;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    class AdminSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            //
            DB::table( 'admins' )->insert([
               'name' => 'rafa',
               'email' =>'rafa@email.com',
                'password' => Hash::make('password'),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Admin Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'profile_photo_url',
    ];
}
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ]
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ]

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ]
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

It redirects to the dashboard when login as a user. But when login as a admin it says These credentials do not match our records. Please , fix me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do not implement custom login etc. use the ones provided by Laravel fortify (that serves the purpose of using that) .
Plus laravel fortify already registers routes for the views.
just create the views and use them as it is.